# Download File Online Using lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I am trying to download a file from the internet via a python script. I am using the "mechanize" module to access the web but then when I try to follow links it gives an html read error as the web page is in lxml format. My code is below:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/v2/")
```

Next I would normally do the following:

```
request = br.retrieve('link.zip')[0]
```

However this produces the html error mentioned. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: "the web page is in lxml format". What does that mean? This question does not seem to be related to lxml (http://lxml.de) at all.

Comment: I used selenium to read the file and it told me the page was in lxml (might mean xml) format

Comment: When I run the code in the question, I get "ValueError: unknown url type: link.zip".